# Remove/stop "googlebot" from killing site bandwidth

Tags: web-crawler, bandwidth, googlebot

In a magento site, 32 gb "bandwidth" is wasted by "Not viewed traffic includes traffic generated by robots, worms, or replies with special HTTP status codes."

Googlebot alone is using 29.41 gb. I wanted to avoid all these "Robots/spiders" consuming bandwidth.

Mainly How to  remove atleast "googlebot".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent Googlebot from overwhelming site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328436/how-to-prevent-googlebot-from-overwhelming-site)

Comment: hi Michael, thanks a lot for reply. please visit this link : http://albedoeventz.com/robots.txt is it enough to block googlebot from visiting the site http://albedoeventz.com/